# "ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE- How to add the items that i will choose and subtract it to the cash?"

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

How do I add the items that I will choose and subtract it from the cash that I will input?

```
org 100h   
LEA DX, ASKQUESTION     ;Ask question to proceed or quit
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H

CMP AL, 71h
JE PQ
JNE PROCEED

PROCEED:
LEA dx, NEWLINE         ;new line
MOV ah, 9h 
INT 21h 

LEA dx, CHOOSE          ;Choose msg
MOV ah, 9h 
INT 21h 

LEA DX, PROD1
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H 

LEA DX, PROD2
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H

LEA DX, PROD3
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H

LEA DX, PROD4
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H

LEA DX, NEWLINE
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H  

GETITEM:
LEA DX, ITEM  
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h

MOV AH, 01h
INT 21H

CMP AL, 0dh
JE NOTICE                 ;jump if AL=0dh to NOTICE 

CMP AL, 31h
JE l1

CMP AL, 32h
JE l2 

CMP AL, 33h
JE l3

CMP AL, 34h
JE l4
JNE WARNING

l1:                       ;firstItem
MOV CL, 36h
MOV BL, 35h
MOV ITM11, CL
MOV ITM12, BL 

JMP GOLOOPING

l2:                       ;2ND ITEM
MOV CH, 34H
MOV BH, 35H
MOV ITM21, CH
MOV ITM22, BH

JMP GOLOOPING

l3:                        ;THIRD ITEM 
MOV CH, 32H
MOV CL, 30H
MOV ITM31, CH
MOV ITM32, CL

JMP GOLOOPING

l4:                        ;4TH ITEM 
MOV BH, 38H
MOV BL, 30H
MOV ITM41, BH
MOV ITM42, BL


GOLOOPING:
LEA DX, LOOPING
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H

CMP AL, 79h
JNE GOPAYMENT
JE GETITEM

NOTICE: 
LEA DX, NOTICEMSG
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h

JMP GETITEM

WARNING:
LEA DX, OOPS
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

JMP GETITEM

PQ:                 ;proceed or Quit
LEA DX, QUIT
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

INT 20h             ;to terminate program

GOPAYMENT:
LEA DX, NEWLINE
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

LEA DX, PAYMENT
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H  

LEA DX, NEWLINE
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

LEA DX, CASH
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
MOV BH, AL

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
MOV BL, AL

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
MOV CL, AL

CHOOSE DB 13,10, " CHOOSE PRODUCT: $"
PROD1 DB 13,10, "   1. WATERMELON   P65$"  
PROD2 DB 13,10, "   2. MELON        P45$"
PROD3 DB 13,10, "   3. Banana       P20$"
PROD4 DB 13,10, "   4. Mango Steam  P80$"

NEWLINE DB 13,10, " $" 
SHOWPRICEITEMS DB 13,10, "  P $" 
ITEM DB 13,10, "Enter item: $"
LOOPING DB 13,10, "Do you want to choose more(y/n)? $"
PAYMENT DB 13,10, "--------PAYMENT--------$"
CASH DB 13,10, "    Cash:        $"
NOTICEMSG DB 13,10, "NOTICE: You need to input items.$"
OOPS DB 13,10, "Wrong Input!"
ASKQUESTION DB 13,10, "Want to proceed or quit(p/q)?$"
QUIT DB 13,10, "----Bye-------$"

ITM11 DB 00H
ITM12 DB 00H
ITM21 DB 00H
ITM22 DB 00H
ITM31 DB 00H
ITM32 DB 00H
ITM41 DB 00H
ITM42 DB 00H  

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by converting the **cash** into an integer.

```
LEA DX, CASH
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
sub al,48
mov ah,100
mul ah
mov bx,ax

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
sub al,48
mov ah,10
mul ah
add bx,ax

MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
sub al,48
mov ah,0
add bx,ax
```

Next convert the value of item1 into another integer and subtract it from the **cash** integer in BX register. Only do this if item1 was effectively bought!

```
DeductItem1:
 mov al,ITM11
 cmp al,0
 je Item1WasNotBought
 sub al,48
 mov ah,10
 mul ah
 mov cx,ax

 mov al,ITM12
 sub al,48
 mov ah,0
 add cx,ax

 sub bx,cx
Item1WasNotBought:
```

Repeat the previous step for items 2, 3, and 4.

Now BX holds the cash to return.